# How to calculate the probability of rolling X or less on Y dice

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients

For example, if I have 3 (six-sided) dice and I want to know the probability of rolling 4 or less, how would I calculate that?  I want to use a spreadsheet and take as input X and Y, so I'm looking for something formulaic.

Thanks!

Comment: Look up generating functions.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2068036/probability-that-x-ge-y-given-n-rolls-on-a-d20/2069186#2069186.

Comment: That would work if I knew X and Y.  I'm hoping for something like a combinatorial formula.  I know that you can use this approach to calculate the probability of rolling exactly X.  Is there a similar approach for "X or less"?  Thanks.